# C# Inconsistent work with access databases (OleDb)

Tags: database, ms-access

I've found a really annoying inconsistency in working with access databases with C#.

I use this code to add movie info to my database, and it works:

```
            var startupPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
        System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + startupPath + "\\baza.accdb");
        con.Open();
        OleDbCommand comm = con.CreateCommand();
        comm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Film (Naziv, Autor, Slika, Adresa, Godina) VALUES('"+textBox1.Text+ "', '" + textBox2.Text + "', '" + textBox3.Text + "', '" + textBox4.Text + "', '" + textBox5.Text + "'); ";
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        this.Close();
```

But, when I try to use the same syntax to write info about users, it doesn't work (Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.):

```
            var startupPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
        System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
        OleDbConnection con1 = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + startupPath + "\\baza.accdb");
        con1.Open();
        OleDbCommand comm1 = con1.CreateCommand();
        comm1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Korisnik (Username, Password, Tip) VALUES('" + textBox1.Text + "', '" + textBox2.Text + "', 'Korisnik');";
        comm1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con1.Close();
        this.Close();
```

Both are ran on a button press, and the second one does work when I run it through Microsoft Access 2016, but returns an error when ran through my app. The syntax is the same, so I really have no idea why its not working... Any help is appreciated.

PS: I also have a button for changing the admins password:

```
            var startupPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
        System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + startupPath + "\\baza.accdb");
        con.Open();
        OleDbCommand comm = con.CreateCommand();
        comm.CommandText = "Update Korisnik Set Password = '"+ Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Izaberite novu šifru", "Filmoteka", "", -1, -1) + "' Where Username = 'admin'";
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();            
        con.Close();
```

But that one returns an error too :(

Comment: Your code is wide open to SQL inyection, a simple quote in a name may create a syntax error (in the best of cases). Always use parametrize the queries. Also, show what error, so we're not just guessing.

Comment: `Password` is a [reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html#P).  Either change the field name or bracket it like `[Password]` in your SQL statements.

Comment: @HansUp Thanks, that solved my second problem :)
Now I need to figure out how to solve the first one xD

Comment: Do you mean this didn't work? --> `INSERT INTO Korisnik (Username, [Password], Tip)`

Comment: @Alejandro I solved my problem by adding brackets.

Comment: @HansUp It works now after I added the brackets. I added the brackets to the password for admin password changing, but later realized that I have the word password for user adding too. Thanks for the tip :) Everything works now!

Comment: @BoskoSinobad Good.  But don't dismiss Alejandro's suggestion to use parameter queries.